# How can I post a story to the Facebook Wall using iPhone Graph API?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, facebook-graph-api

I want to post something on the user wall. I used the below code to post on the user wall but I'm getting a blank screen as soon as I log in. Can anyone help out?

```
(void) fbDidLogin {

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
[defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
[defaults synchronize];

NSString *kAppId;
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               kAppId, @"109133762519851",
                               @"http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/", @"link",
                               @"http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg", @"picture",
                               @"Facebook Dialogs", @"name",
                               @"Reference Documentation", @"caption",
                               @"Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for apps to interact with users.", @"description",
                               @"Facebook Dialogs are so easy!",  @"message",
                               nil];

[facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params  andDelegate:self];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did u try with

```
 [facebook dialog: @"stream.publish" andParams: params andDelegate:self];
```

http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/how-to-develop-facebook-application-for-iphone/

Comment: i tried ur above code still getting an empty screen after login

Comment: its working good..i made the mistake of not assigning my appid on the variable...KAPPID....

Answer (score 1):

See PostFeed method in [Facebook graph api](https://github.com/reallylongaddress/iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API)

Answer (score 1):

See if you can make use of this:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

Comment: i ve copied the source file of "facebook-ios-sdk"into my app it works fine..i ve refered the facebook.com/mobile everything works fine except for the mobile dialogue..wat i mention above am i doing any mistake in the above code...

Comment: thanks for ur effort...its working good i havent assigned the app id